# Javascript ES6 custom sort method not working all the times

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, ecmascript-6

I want to sort my JSON output.

I made my own sort method for it as you can see here:

```
const sortAsc = (propertyName) => (a, b) => a[propertyName] === b[propertyName] ? 0 : a[propertyName] < b[propertyName] ? -1 : 1;
const sortDesc = (propertyName) => (a, b) => a[propertyName] === b[propertyName] ? 0 : a[propertyName] < b[propertyName] ? 1 : -1;
```

I call it like so:

```
asc(value) {
    this.result.sort(this.sortAsc(value));
}
```

It works sort of but when I sort it it doesn't sort right always.

Take a look at this little gif:
https://gyazo.com/5f590f7c921eb1cb3bc4138f85c2162b

As you see it doesn't really work with the ID. It works ascending on `Naam` (name in dutch) But when descending it first gives 2 names starting with v & k. Why is that?

Well, If that's something what is hard to be fixed it isn't really a problem. As long it can sort numbers aswell as strings.

One more thing to note is that I am using Angular 4.4.4. I googled for a build-in sort/orderBy function but found that's not build-in. But if there is anything I can use that Angular provides to make it easier I would be happy to use it!

**EDIT:**

My new methods:

```
sortAsc = (propertyName) => (a, b) => a[propertyName].localeCompare(b[propertyName]);
```

Comment: You probably want to use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) when comparing strings. This also lets you configure how lower/upper case words are sorted.

Comment: The `v` and `k` might be a case-sensitive thing. I've seems similar issues on certain databases where a lowercase `a` is considered to be after an uppercase `Z`. Perhaps try to `.toLower()` in your comparison functions?

Comment: It looks like it works just fine. By default, string inequalities use unicode code points (which includes ASCII), so in descending order you have lowercase letters, and then uppercase letters.

Comment: It's not your question but you should definitely implement sortDesc as -1 * sortAsc(...) instead of duplicating.

Comment: Okay, I have changed my method as @FelixKling pointed out to use `LocaleCompare` and it works for string now. But I stull have the problem with the numbers. How do I solve that?

Comment: Please post your actual data (or a subset of it necessary to reproduce the problem) in JSON format. A gif is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with option:

> The **`localeCompare()`** method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.
>
> The new `locales` and `options` arguments let applications specify the language whose sort order should be used and customize the behavior of the function. In older implementations, which ignore the `locales` and `options` arguments, the locale and sort order used are entirely implementation dependent.

```
const sortAsc = propertyName => (a, b) =>
    a[propertyName].localeCompare(b[propertyName], undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });


const sortDesc = (propertyName) => (a, b) =>
    -a[propertyName].localeCompare(b[propertyName], undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
```

Comment: That's really good to know. I've never noticed the options before. However, you've got a problem - numbers don't have the `localeCompare` method. Using `a[propertyName].toString().localeCompare()`  seems to work fine.

Comment: right, converting is necessary for a string method.

Comment: I don't see a good reason to use `localCompare` over the usual relational operators - they work on strings just fine. Notice also that the `options` is new in ES6, and won't work in older browsers.

Comment: @Bergi, the question has `const`, so it is an ES6 question.

Comment: @Nina, Thanks for showing the comparison options which many novice developers (including myself) often overlook/are unaware of. I wish there was a way to "subscribe" to you and your SO answers, because it's the second thing I learnt from you within the last 12 hours.

Comment: Also, I can't see how `localeCompare` is a solution to a problem where relational operators don't work. Can you give an example where they lead to different results?

Comment: Hmmmm... This actually works perfectly! I do not need to add `.toString()` and it orders perfectly as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This affects string columns sorting as well: `[{model: 'test 10 ab'}, {model: 'test 12 ab'}, {model: 'test 111 ab'}]` - will no longer be sorted as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want to compare Ids as numbers, so you should use appropriate sorting functions for number-like columns:

```
const sortAsc = (propertyName) => (a, b) => a[propertyName] === b[propertyName] ? 0 : +a[propertyName] < +b[propertyName] ? -1 : 1;
const sortDesc = (propertyName) => (a, b) => a[propertyName] === b[propertyName] ? 0 : +a[propertyName] < +b[propertyName] ? 1 : -1;
```

Another way is to adjust you table data array, ids should be numbers there, not strings, in this case your sorting functions should also work.

Answer (score -1):

Your comparison functions are totally fine. The relational operators work out of the box on both numbers and strings, there's no reason to use `localeCompare`.

> It works sort of but when I sort it it doesn't sort right always: it doesn't really work with the ID.

It appears that the `id` properties in your array of objects are strings, so they are compared lexicographically. Make them actual numbers and they'll be compared as numbers.

> It works ascending on `Naam` But when descending it first gives 2 names starting with v & k. Why is that?

It's really hard to see in the gif, but it appears that those two weirdly sorted values begin with a space - which is always sorted first. Make sure your data is valid.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but the reason why it first started with v & k is because they are not lowercase letters. Changing it to localeComare fixed that issue. I don't know if my id's are strings, I don't think so because I cast them to a number like so: `id: <number> null`. What I have done now, is I added a new sort method for numbers: `(propertyName) => (a, b) => a[propertyName] - (b[propertyName]);` This probably is not the best solution, but the code looks good and maintainable and it's quick.

Comment: Is that a TypeScript declaration? I don't think it's a cast - and definitely not happening in the place where you assign the actual value (not just `null`).

Comment: Yes, I think it's TypeScript. Hmmmm... so, not a cast. Well it is in C# :P I'm a bit new to TypeScript, Angular and ES6.