# Microsoft Edge array.sort(compareFunction) not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Microsoft Edge Version: 41.16299.402.0

I've noticed an oddity with Edge in that providing an anonymous function with array.sort() doesn't appear to sort my array of objects correctly. My function works in Firefox and Chrome though. The code below serves as an example of the issue I'm running into:

```
data = [
    {title: "First", language: "English"}, 
    {title: "Second", language: "Armenian"},
    {title: "Third", language: "Cantonese"}
];

data.forEach(function(val){
    console.log(val);
});

data.sort(function(a,b) { console.log(a.language > b.language); return a.language > b.language;});

data.forEach(function(val){
    console.log(val);
});
```

If you run that code in JSFiddle in Chrome or Firefox, you'll notice that the second set of console logs is sorted alphabetically by language. Run it in Edge however and there won't be any difference between the two sets. I'm assuming that this has to do with how I am handling sort() and not a bug in Edge (seems like something that would have been fixed a long time ago if that were the case). Does anyone know what's wrong with my sort syntax?

Screenshot of console log from **Chrome**:
[image]

Screenshot of console log from **Edge**:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you return the value of a comparison, which is either `true` or `false`, which is interpreted as numerical value of `1` and `0`. Basically it misses the value of `-1` which is necessary to return a sucessfull sorting.

```js
var data = [{ title: "First", language: "English" }, { title: "Second", language: "Armenian" }, { title: "Third", language: "Cantonese" }];

data.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a.language > b.language || -(a.language < b.language);
});

console.log(data);
```

Just for completeness, for strings, you could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) which has some more features, like natural sorting, or localized possiblities.

```js
var data = [{ title: "First", language: "English" }, { title: "Second", language: "Armenian" }, { title: "Third", language: "Cantonese" }];

data.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a.language.localeCompare(b.language);
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked. I'm assuming then that Chrome and Firefox are doing extra work in the background for me to help me avoid these pitfalls?

Comment: And according to [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it is supported by Edge

Comment: Have you any explanation for why OP's code would work in other browsers?

Comment: it looks like edge is respecting zero return as ok, where as all other implementations the values with zero gets another check.

Comment: Why the complexity? Just `return a.language.localeCompare(b.language)` would be sufficient and also (potentially) locale-aware. No need for `<` and `>` (and the coercion from boolean to number).

Comment: the old question ... ;-) yes, this would work shorter, but some ppl think it should be avoided. anyway in the contect of the question and by using a comparator, i showed to take another comparison for getting the negative value as well with it.

Comment: @NinaScholz - Do these people give a reason for avoiding `localeCompare`? (Example?) It's entire purpose is to compare strings in a locale-specific way (where available) and return exactly the values `sort` expects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, see bergi's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796731/javascript-es6-custom-sort-method-not-working-all-the-times

Comment: @NinaScholz - He doesn't offer any reason there. Whereas it's clear from the spec that there *is* a good reason to use `localeCompare` (if comparing strings where locale should be considered and not, say, GUIDs): [`localeCompare`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.localecompare) vs. the [abstract relational comparison](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison). Note that the latter is done in terms of code units, not meaningful string comparison. *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* On that same question, [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796731/#comment80540226_46796731) noted that `localeCompare` would likely be the better option.